# Mapping Two Classes Properties and Values Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using linq to map two similar objects, but I am having an issue that it does not map subclasses it does not even see them in the GetProperties(). The sub classes are marked as public so I am a little confused why this code is not working... Any ideas or suggestions on using the other method/s. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in _WorkRequest.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
 _WorkRequestV1.GetType().GetProperty(pInfo.Name).SetValue(_WorkRequestV1, pInfo.GetValue(_WorkRequest, null), null);
}
```

**UPDATE**

After looking into this I have noticed that when declaring a subclass within a class ex:

```
public Person myPerson;
```

GetProperties() does **not** see Person class but if I add

```
public Person myPerson {get;set;}
```

GetProperties() **does** see myPerson

Lastly if I add

```
public Person myPerson = new Person()
```

GetProperties() does **not** see the person.

How come it required {get;set}?

Comment: Well, `public Person myPerson` is not a property but a field. `public Person myPerson {get;set;}` is a property. How do you execute `GetProperties` after `public Person myPerson = new Person()`?

Comment: @GertArnold What do you mean how do I execute GetProperties what I do is this List<PropertyInfo> myList = _WorkRequest.GetType().GetProperties().ToList(); where inside my _WorkRequest class I have Person myPerson = new Person as a property.

Comment: You should show more code. If Person is a public property of the WorkRequest class it should show up in GetProperties().

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your code why this wouldn't work, but there is a better way to copy properties of one object to another object and that is by using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

You can do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WorkRequest, WorkRequestV1>();
Mapper.Map(_WorkRequest, _WorkRequestV1);
```

Comment: thanks for a quick response. I have tried using AutoMapper but I get an exception Trying to map the two objects. I have made the classes identical and still get an error. Could it be due to sub classes? AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.